# How to declare LLVM arguments from within the code?

Tags: compilation, rust, llvm

I want to compile a module with a specific LLVM argument. I know about the `-C llvm-args='..'` command line argument to rustc, but I don't want to have to ask whoever deploys the code to remember the command line.

Is there a way to put such arguments in the code (similar to `#[link_args(..)]`)?

Comment: For my own curiosity, what argument(s)? Would something like a Makefile be an out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: One example would be setting unroll_threshold, another to skip some time-consuming passes. I hope to get away from make, actually...

Comment: maybe you need a build script [link](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html)

Comment: for more interactive responses i suggest going on the irc channel rust-beginners on mozilla node